# Creating object that animates when changing its attributes(ie. visible, etc.)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been looking through things with animations in javascript and AngularJS and I would like to create a javascript object such that if I were to write something like

```html
obj.visible = true
```

the resulting object would become visible and other similar functions. Is there any such way to define an object that would change when one of its attributes would change? I know there are many animation functions available that do the same thing, but is there any way to incorporate such functions into a javascript object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily run a function when a "property" is set to a different value by using Classes and getters / setters like so:

```js
class AnimatedObject {  
  set visible(visibility) {
    // do something with visibility
    console.log("visibility is now", visibility);
  }
}

let obj = new AnimatedObject();

obj.visible = true;

obj.visible = "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = { /* your object content here */ }

// Now check if the object's 'visible' property has a value 'true' or not
//using if statement and changing visibility of an element based on the result

if (obj.visible == 'true') {
    someName.style.opacity = '1'
} else {
    someName.style.opacity= '0'
}
```

In the above, `someName` is a hypothetical variable assigned to an HTML element rendered from your object.

---

Check the fiddle below for an example of changing as well as toggling visibility using an object property value.

```js
var obj = { a: '1', b: '2', c: '3', d: '4', visible: 'true' }
var someName = document.getElementById('someDiv');
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

someName.textContent = obj.a + obj.b + obj.c + obj.d;

function checkVisibility(){
    if (obj.visible == 'true') {
        someName.style.opacity = '1'
    } else {
        someName.style.opacity= '0'
    }
}

function changeVisibility(){
 if (obj.visible == 'true') {
   obj.visible = 'false'
  } else {
   obj.visible = 'true'
  }
  
  checkVisibility()
}

btn.addEventListener('click', changeVisibility);
```

```css
#someDiv {padding: 5px; background-color: green;}
```

```html
<button>
ClickMe
</button>
<div id="someDiv"></div>
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/yjpv1s13/